# JQuery onchange event will not fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, triggers

I'm trying to get this example working: [Preview an image before it is uploaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded)

I simplified the code to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#imgInp").change(function () {
        alert('changed');
    });
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <input type='file' id="imgInp" />
        <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />
    </form>
</body>
```

The problem is the change function on imgInp is not getting triggered. I've tried a million things, but can't get it working. What am I missing?

Thanks...

Comment: did you checked console ? are you getting any errors ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to place it inside document.ready function...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#imgInp").change(function () {
    alert('changed');
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the code in DOM ready:

```
$(function(){
  $("#imgInp").change(function () {
    alert('changed');
 });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on("change","#imgInp",function(){
        alert('changed');
    });

    </script>
```

Comment: That is unnecessary use of event delegation. You should only use it when elements are added dynamically.